# ComboBox crashing WPF application because SelectionChanged is firing too soon

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, crash, nullreferenceexception

Here's my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cloneSelector"
          Width="80"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Margin="10"
          SelectionChanged="cloneSelector_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="All" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Top" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Middle" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bottom" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="None" />
</ComboBox>
```

And here is the SelectionChanged handler (as requested by a comment):

```
cloneSelection = (CloneFormat) cloneSelector.SelectedIndex;

var frameSize = videoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize;

    switch (cloneSelection)
    {
        case CloneFormat.Top:
            cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, frameSize.Width, (frameSize.Width* 9) / 16);
            break;
        case CloneFormat.Middle:
            cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 100, frameSize.Width, (frameSize.Width* 9) / 16);
            break;
        case CloneFormat.Bottom:
            cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 200, frameSize.Width, (frameSize.Width* 9) / 16);
            break;
        default:
            cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, frameSize.Width, frameSize.Height);
            break;
    }
```

My application runs if `SelectedIndex`, the `SelectionChanged` handler, or the `ComboBoxItems` are removed. The problem seems to be that the handler is accessing `cloneSelector` too soon and throwing a null object exception. Is there an easy way to prevent this behavior while still maintaining my functionality (i.e. not having SelectedIndex start at -1)?

Also, if I didn't test my project so frequently I would've had no idea what I did to break it. It builds successfully and fails silently. When I debug, the Exception Unhandled box in the No Symbols Loaded designer says

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Inner Exception

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And I can see that it was thrown in PresentationFramework.dll but it gives me no information about what was null or what's causing the error. How do I get better debugging info, i.e. get it to tell me that the `ComboBox` is the source of the crash?

Comment: Please add the SelectionChanged handler to the question.

Comment: Oh hold on. That's a good call. I think videoDevice is what's actually null.

Comment: During your debug be sure that the checkbox "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the "Exception Settings" view is Checked. That will be more easy to debug.

Comment: That actually works, I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my `ComboBox` wasn't even the null reference, it was my video resolution object. All the more reason I need more specific debugging info.