# Application level cached objects should be threadsafe?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

I am thinking to use `HttpContext.Current.Cache` which has application level scope. I know that Cache object is thread safe but the thing that i don't understand is cached objects are not thread safe so how it is possible to use and modify them thread safely ???

Answer (score 4):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) article the `Cache` type is thread safe but caching `not thread safe` object may cause unexpected errors.

Here is very good thread (stackoverflow) on [Thread-safe cache libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330275/thread-safe-cache-libraries-for-net/4382803#4382803) and MSDN article on Object Caching (Sharepoint) - [Object Caching Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558270.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is your own responsibility to make sure that the objects placed in the cache are thread-safe.

Comment: Exactly. Either objects should be thread-safe, or you should replace them completely by a new instance (threat them as immutable objects). Best is to *not* update parts of objects inside your cache. Just use read-only lists of immutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

If different threads are going to use and modify the cached objects concurrently then you will need some application level protocol. This can be either as simple as `lock(cachedObject) {....}`

If you can determine that something in the cache is only accessed by a single thread at a time or that it cannot be modified (because it is immutable) then you don't need anything further.

What it means for `HttpContext.Current.Cache` to be threadsafe is that multiple threads can get and put stuff in it concurrently. So if you want some co-ordination between multiple keys then you will need some higher level locking.